# How to access 'response' parameter of app.get in callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I want to pass a list of files (`obj`) that I'm getting through a google drive API to EJS files.

i.e. I want to write

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index',obj);
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the js object through a few call back functions.
This function is called

```
fs.readFile('client_secret.json',processClientSecrets );
```

which in turn calls,

```
function processClientSecrets(err,content) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
  return;
}else{
  authorize(JSON.parse(content),findFiles);
 }
}
```

which calls these two,

```
function authorise(credentials,callback) {
var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}
```

[EDIT]

```
function findFiles(auth){
var obj ={};
var key = 'files';
obj[key]=[];
var drive = google.drive('v3');
drive.files.list({
                auth: auth,
                folderId: '****************',
                q: "mimeType contains 'application/pdf' and trashed = false"
                },
  function(err,response){
    var f = response.files;
    if (f.length == 0) {
    console.log('No files found.');
    }else {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        var file = f[i];
        //console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
        obj[key].push(file.name + ' ' + file.id);
        }
        console.log(obj);
        return obj;
  }
                  });

}
```

This looks like a very basic question, however im not able to solve it as node.js is asynchronous in nature and all my attempts to return obj have resulted in rendering of obj before retrieving it.

Comment: the control reaches readFile then goes to Authorize (I am able to log the object returned by authorize) but after that it catches an error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to callback hell. :-) The old "Node" way would be to do nested callbacks, which gets very ugly very quickly.

The modern approach is to use promises, which makes it easier to compose multiple async operations together. Make your own async functions return promises, and for Node API functions (or add-on libs that don't provide promises yet), use wrappers to make them promise-enabled (manually, or by using something like [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify)).

With promise-based functions, for instance, your call would look like this:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    readFilePromise('client_secret.json')
        .then(content => JSON.parse(content))
        .then(authorise)
        .then(findFiles)
        .then(files => {
            res.render('index', files);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // Render error here
        });
});
```

or since neither `JSON.parse` nor `findFiles` is asynchronous:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    readFilePromise('client_secret.json')
        .then(content => authorise(JSON.parse(content)))
        .then(auth => {
            res.render('index', findFiles(auth));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // Render error here
        });
});
```

It's fine to use non-async functions with `then` provided the function expects one parameter and returns the processed result, so the first version was fine too, though there is a *bit* of overhead involved.

In both cases, `readFilePromise` is a promisified version of `readFile`, and `authorize` looks *something* like this:

```
function authorise(credentials) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    return readFilePromise(TOKEN_PATH)
        .then(token => {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            return oauth2Client;
        });
}
```

*(Also note — subjectivity warning! — that because we don't end up with hellish deeply-nested callback structures, we can use a reasonable indentation width rather than the two spaces so many Node programmers felt the need to adopt.)*

Moving forward further, if you're using Node V8.x+, you could use `async`/`await` syntax to consume those promises:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res){
    try {
        const credentials = JSON.parse(await readFilePromise('client_secret.json'));
        const auth = await authorize(credentials);
        const files = findFiles(auth);
        res.render('index', files);
    } catch (e) {
        // Render error here
    }
});
```

Note the `async` before `function` and the `await` any time we're calling a function that returns a promise. An `async` function returns a promise under the covers, and `await` consumes promises under the covers. The code *looks* synchronous, but isn't. Every `await` is effectively a call to `then` registering a callback for when the promise completes. Similarly, the `try`/`catch` is effectively a call to the `catch` method on the promise chain.

We could condense that if we wanted:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res){
    try {
        res.render('index', findFiles(await authorize(JSON.parse(await readFilePromise('client_secret.json'))));
    } catch (e) {
        // Render error here
    }
});
```

...but readability/debuggability suffer. :-)

Important note: When passing an `async` function into something (like `app.get`) that isn't expecting the function to return a promise, you *must* wrap it in a `try`/`catch` as above and handle any error, because if the calling code isn't expecting a promise, it won't handle promise rejections, and you need to do that; unhandled rejections are a bad thing (and in future versions of Node will cause your process to terminate).

If what you're passing an `async` function into **does** expect a function returning a process, best to leave the `try/`catch` off and allow errors to propagate.

---

You asked for help with `findFiles`. I recommend learning `promisify` or something similar. The right way (to my mind) to solve this is to give yourself a promisified version of `drive.files.list`, since `drive.files.list` uses Node-style callbacks instead.

But without promisifying it, we can do this:

```
function findFiles(auth) {
    var drive = google.drive('v3');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        drive.files.list({
            auth: auth,
            folderId: '****************',
            q: "mimeType contains 'application/pdf' and trashed = false"
        },
        function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            var f = response.files;
            if (f.length == 0) {
                console.log('No files found.');
            }
            else {
                var key = 'files'; // Why this indirection??
                resolve({[key]: f.map(file => file.name + ' ' + file.id)});
                // Without the indirection it would be:
                // resolve({files: f.map(file => file.name + ' ' + file.id)});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If we had a promisified version, and we did away with the `key` indirection which seems unnecessary, it would be simpler:

```
function findFiles(auth) {
    return drivePromisified.files.list({
        auth: auth,
        folderId: '****************',
        q: "mimeType contains 'application/pdf' and trashed = false"
    }).then(files => ({files: files.map(file => file.name + ' ' + file.id)}));
}
```

Or as an `async` function using `await`:

```
async function findFiles(auth) {
    const files = await drivePromisified.files.list({
        auth: auth,
        folderId: '****************',
        q: "mimeType contains 'application/pdf' and trashed = false"
    });
    return {files: files.map(file => file.name + ' ' + file.id)};
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer, actually my `findFile` function is also async , would you be kind enough to help me promisify that too,

Comment: @AlwaysHungrie: Tricky as you haven't shown its content. :-) But it's best as an exercise for the reader anyway: Just have it return a promise. For instance, if uses [`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback), you'd promisify that like we did `readFile` above, and return the promise from it (possibly with `then` chained on it if you need to transform the results).

Comment: sorry about that, I edited the question to include `findFile`, i tried returning drive.files.list however the code just goes to the catch(e) block.

Comment: @AlwaysHungrie: I do recommend spending some time on promise tutorials, and getting to know `promisify` or similar. You're coming to this stuff at a time when you don't have to learn the old callback hell way of doing things, you can jump over that to the cleaner land of `async`/`await` (or at least promises). I've added to the end of the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: The solutions you gave me cleared all my concepts of Promises :). Hopefully now I would be able to write async code without errors now on. **I cannot Thank You enough**